# error while building tensorflow on android, using bazel support

Tags: android, gradle, tensorflow, build.gradle, bazel

As mentioned here in the link below
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android#android-studio

"At this point you can add the tensorflow/examples/android directory as a new Android Studio project."

All that I did

1. Cloned git repo using "git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git"
2. Built an APK using "bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo"
3. Found the APK in "**/.../.../tensorflow-master/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/android**"
4. As mentioned above, I tried to add "**tensorflow/examples/android**"
   directory as a new Android Studio project
5. As mentioned in the link above "look at ***build.gradle*** and make sure that the path to Bazel matches that of your system." I changed it to "def bazelLocation = **'/usr/bin/bazel'**"

The Error

I am trying to build an APK from the Android Studio and found this error

**Error:Execution failed for task ':buildExternalAssets'.
Process 'command '/usr/bin/bazel'' finished with non-zero exit value 1**

***Gradle Build Messages***

Executing tasks: [:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:javaPreCompileDebug
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:buildExternalAssets

Couldn't find java at '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java'.

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':buildExternalAssets'.

Process 'command '/usr/bin/bazel'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.433 secs

Comment: That's Gradle standard error message. You're missing the real error message, and have forgotten the Gradle build log in your question. Please [edit] your question to include it

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for responding, hope it helps now

Comment: Java 8 is now version 120, so however it's looking for that version, I'd try installing the jdk again and see if that fixes your paths

Comment: I have jdk1.8.0_121 at "/usr/bin/java", and I installed it after deleting java from all other folders. Since java was required at "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java", for the program to compile, I also installed it. Can you please explain the requirement @cricket_007

Comment: I have no idea what `bazel` is, sorry. `/usr/bin/java` should be a symbolic link into `/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java`. If you only deleted the other folders, then you've done something wrong because you're supposed to uninstall, not just delete. Besides, that, I don't know what operating system you're on

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit, thanks for the info about symbolic link. Initially I deleted java from "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java", using java purge command and did fresh installation at "user/bin/java" Bazel is just a tool to compile and generate android APK with tensorflow.

Comment: I only said it should be, but you should `echo $JAVA_HOME` and then `ls -l $(which java)` to know where files are pointing to. If the Java home variable is empty, then you must set that up. Otherwise, Android Studio needs to be setup to point at your new Java 8 installation

Comment: java at **/user/bin** points to following location
**lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root,22 Mar 17 10:01 java -> /etc/alternatives/java** and java at **/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java** dosent point to any location. On using **echo  $JAVA_HOME**, I get **/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/** on using gedit /etc/profile I see $JAVA_HOME pointing to **/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_101** and Android Studio Jdk is pointing to **/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_101**

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007, for helping me understand and solve issues with java PATH variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @cricket_007 for responding and clearing my concepts about jdk installation

To solve the issue above

1. Open **"build.gradle"** at [/.../.../.../tensorflow-master/tensorflow/examples/android/build.gradle], check for

   "**def externalModelData** = '../../../***bazel-tensorflow-master***/external'"
2. Verify that **def externalModelData** is pointing to the correct folder name, initially it was '../../../***bazel-tensorflow***/external'
3. I had to change it to **bazel-tensorflow-master**, these are the folders generated by bazel, after you compile the tensorflow sources from github on your command line, using bazel, Android SDK and Android NDK tools
4. Also make sure that your Jdk installation is perfect.